# Why does Mathematica fail to solve my equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve an equation using *Mathematica*, but I keep getting the 
following error

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods 
>   available to Solve.

More importantly, it is running for more than half an hour without giving any solution. I have also tried `Reduce`, but that does not work either.

Any suggestions? How I can fix the error? I am new to *Mathematica*. My apologies if this is a very basic question.

I am trying to find θ1 (angle)?

```
x = (e*b*Cos[θ1] + v)^2/(v^2 + e^2*b^2 + 2*e*v*b*Cos[θ1])

Eq2 = a^2 + e*(Sin[θ]- Sin[θ1]) + v/b(θ-θ1)-a*Sqrt[x] == 
   a^2*x + e^2*(Cos[θ]-Cos[θ1])^2- 2*a*e*(Cos[θ]-Cos[θ1])*Sqrt[x]

Solve[Eq2, θ1]
```

Comment: inside the square bracket is theta just pls type in mathematica Theta rathar then 01 let you know ta

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please [take a look at the FAQ when posting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq). Regarding your comment, just know that you can still edit your question after it has been posted. Also, please try to block out your code (look at the [editing help link.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)).

Comment: Your equation cannot be handled by `Solve`; you can use `FindRoot` to get a numerical solution once you specify a numerical value for the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ,However when i used Find root i got this error.... the function value is not a list of numbers with dimensions...FindRoot[Eq2, θ1,Reals] or i wrote [Eq2, θ1,-Pi,Pi] didnt work :(Could you pls help me how would you write the a numerical value for the paremeters Thank u

Answer (score 4):

Many classes of equations cannot be solved analytically. If you know the values of your parameters you could use a numerical approach:

```
Block[{e = 1, b = 2, v = 3, a = 4, θ = 5}, 
 FindRoot[Eq2, {θ1, 1}]
]
```

> {θ1 -> 0.9082966746}